# Implementing map for an intensionally-defined set in Scala

Tags: scala

```
  type Set = Int => Boolean

  /**
   * Returns whether all bounded integers within `s` satisfy `p`.
   */
  def forall(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = {
    def iter(a: Int): Boolean = {
      if (a > bound) true
      else if (contains(s, a) && !p(a)) false
      else iter(a + 1)
    }
    iter(-bound)
  }

  /**
   * Returns whether there exists a bounded integer within `s`
   * that satisfies `p`.
   */
  def exists(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = !forall(s, (x => !p(x)))

  /**
   * Returns a set transformed by applying `f` to each element of `s`.
   */
  def map(s: Set, f: Int => Int): Set =  (x => exists(s, (y: Int) => f(y) ==
x))
```

so for this piece of code. I don't understand function `map`.

I see its input are 2 arguments, which are set and method f. But the "body" part, I tried so hard but still don't get it. And what is that `"y"`, and why using f(y) == x makes it apply method f to set elemtns?

need some explanation for me.
thank you!

Comment: You should include your definition of `Set`, otherwise this question won't make sense to anyone who hasn't taken the Scala Coursera ;)

Comment: To explain my edit to the question's summary: see [intensional definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensional_definition).

Comment: Didn't read the Coursera Honor Code, then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be succinct:

If you say: `val set2 = map(set1, f)`,

then `set2(x)` will returns true if and only if there exits `y` in `set1` such as `f(y) == x`

That's exactly what `exists(set1, y => f(y) == x)` is checking.

To put it an other way, an integer is in `set2` only if you can obtain it by applying `f` to an element of `set1`.

Comment: Was struggling to understand this for a bit of time. Your answer explained it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We can try to understand this piece of code by applying it backwards.

The `map` method here would return `true` for every given `x` and function `f`, if `x` is a result of the function `f` applied to the elements of the original set.

It is done by checking that if we go over the original map and apply `f` to every element of this map, at least one of them will be equal to `x` (that is what the part `(x => exists(s, (y: Int) => f(y) == x))` does).

Regarding `exists` itself, it is a statement that if we go over all elements of the set (using `forall` method) with a given predicate `p`, for at least one of the elements this predicate will not be false (this is the part `!forall(s, (x => !p(x)))`).

Answer (score 1):

> And what is that "y"

`exists` takes a function `Int => Boolean` as its second argument. This function is `(y: Int) => f(y) == x`, and `y` is simply the name we give to its argument, same as `x` in `x => !p(x)`.

> and why using f(y) == x makes it apply method f to set elemtns?

This definition says "`x` is a member of `map(s, f)` when `exists(s, y => f(y) == x)`. Now consider a simple case: `s` is the set `{1, 2}` represented by a function `x => (x == 1) || (x == 2)`, and `f = z => z + 1` over it. Then we have

```
s2 = map(s, z => z + 1) = x => exists(s, y => y + 1 == x)
```

by inlining `f` into definition of `map`. You can check that:

1. 2 is a member of `s2`, i.e. `s2(2)` is `exists(s, y => y + 1 == 2)` is `exists(s, y => y == 1)` is `true`.
2. 0 is not a member of `s2`, i.e. `s2(2)` is `exists(s, y => y + 1 == 0)` is `exists(s, y => y == -1)` is `false`.

Thinking a bit more, you should be able to list all members of `s2`, and then to generalize to any `s` and `f`.

Comment: is this "combinator" concept in FP?